# SQL Server stored procedure returns -1 in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not able to figure out what could be the reason for getting -1 for my stored procedure.

Here code behind code (C#):

```
SqlCommand _command = _connection.CreateCommand();
_command.CommandText = "usp_ZX_GetValidToken";
_command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tokenstring", tokenString);
_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@difference", lifeInSeconds);    
Object _response = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_ZX_GetValidToken]
    @tokenstring nvarchar(50), @difference int
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AppAccessTokens 
              WHERE Consumed = 0 AND GUIDToken = RTRIM(@tokenstring) 
                AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateDateTime, GETDATE()) <= @difference)
       RETURN 1;
    ELSE
       RETURN -1;
```

Oh yes! I also make sure that my table have correct data, and I always execute below code before calling procedure:

```
update AppAccessTokens
set CreateDateTime = GETDATE()
```

The `_response` from the above C# code is always `-1`, I am really not able to figure out this on my own. I need a fresh eye to this one.

I have tried restarting machine, server, and IIS. (I know its doesn't make sense) But nothing changes, it keeps returning -1 at all times.

Can anyone suggest what should I do?

Comment: Do not use `RETURN` to return custom value. This is rather sp execution error code (0 - OK , anything else error) **`Return codes are generally used to pass back error checking information`**. Use `SELECT` or `output parameter` instead.

Comment: Or may this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337492/how-to-identify-whether-sql-job-is-successfully-executed-or-not-in-c-sharp

Comment: @lad2025 thanks for the explanation, it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when your SP is executed it will not affect any rows so `ExecuteNonQuery` will return `0` always. Change your SP like this:-

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AppAccessTokens WHERE Consumed = 0 
                  AND GUIDToken = RTRIM(@tokenstring) AND
 DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateDateTime, GETDATE()) <= @difference)
 SELECT 1;
 ELSE
 SELECT -1;
```

Then execute it with `ExecuteScalar` which will read the first row of first column and we are only selecting 1 value in our SP so `_response` will get correct value:-

```
int _response = Convert.ToInt32(_command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Alternatively, you can also use Output parameters.