# ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1

Tags: c#, sql-server, executenonquery

For some reason `result` is always `-1` and nothing get added to the database. I executed the query in SQL Server and it runs fine. I don't get any exception whatsoever and I don't use any stored procedure.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RAINBOW;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ItemDetails.item(description,category_id) VALUES (@item_desc,@cat_id)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_desc", txtitemdesc.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_id", GetCategoryID());
try
{
     con.Open();
     int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     if (result > 0)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully!");
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Failed to add record");
     }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("An error has occured! " + ex);
}
finally
{
     con.Close();
}
```

**Edit**

```
  int GetCategoryID()
        {
            int cat_id = 0;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT category_id FROM ItemDetails.category  WHERE category_desc=@cat_desc", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_desc", cboCategory.Text);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cat_id = int.Parse(reader["category_id"].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
            return cat_id;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try a select already if that is also working (but from C#)?  One thing that is always a good thing to control is the connectionstring if it is correct and if it works as intended (a plain select with no parameters is a good choice there for that test).

Comment: and also did you check if GetCategoryID() and txtitemdesc.Text contain values?

Comment: Remove the `AddWithValue()` and add parameter like this - `cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_desc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = txtitemdesc.Text;`

Comment: @Thomas yes i can confirm that both contain values

Comment: Are there any triggers on this table? Constraints or FKs which might get violated? Perhaps even other columns requiring a value in this table, that could prevent the values being inserted?

Comment: If you use the `select` statement it's a normal behavior because For `select`  statements, the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` is `-1` but since your problem is with `Insert` you should have no problem if you are sure that `GetCategoryID()` and `txtitemdesc.Text` contain values and nothing else prevent the values to being inserted. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32736842/2946329

Comment: @Krishnraj Rana Your code works perfect but why mine was no working.Post it as an answer

Comment: is there any rollback occurs, because in case of rollback  ExecuteNonQuery will return -1, please read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user2650277 it could be (for ranas code) because tht code explicitely tells what sql type is transmitted. Although that is a first that I would see this making a real difference.

Comment: @Thomas while executing applying ranas code i Hardcoded the category id as well but `GetCategoryID()` returns an integer so why it was not working

Comment: Perhaps there is a constraint which prevents duplicates? If that (desc,id) combination already exists, INSERT will fail. It would work the first time, but not afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible then don't use `AddWithValue()`. Actually when you are not providing type explicitly, it will try to convert implicitly and sometimes the implicit conversion may not be the most optimal of conversions. You can find some more discussion **[in this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1200255.aspx)**.

And most important thing is don't forget to clear parameters before assign, by using this line.

`cmd.Parameters.Clears();`

Check below code.

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO ItemDetails.item(description,category_id) VALUES (@item_desc,@cat_id)";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Clears(); // Add this same line in your getcategory function.
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_desc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = txtitemdesc.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cat_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GetCategoryID();

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to add record");
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occured! " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with my code is the `GetCategoryID()`.I coded it to return an integer but somehow i can''t get it to work with `Add` or `AddWithValue` both your code and i work if i hardcode the id

Comment: @user2650277: Can you show us your `GetCategoryID()` function's code in your question ?

Comment: @user2650277: `cboCategory` is combobox ?? if yes then it should be `cboCategory.SelectedValue`

Comment: error happen on the following line `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: @user2650277: Chage this line from `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_desc", cboCategory.Text);` to this line `cmd.Parameters.Add("@cat_desc", SqlDbType.varchar, 500).Value = cboCategory.Text;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96144/discussion-between-user2650277-and-krishnraj-rana).

Comment: i  still get Failed to add record