# Informix 11.7 returns -1 as number of affected rows when using DateTime or string parameter in UPDATE query

Tags: c#, sql, informix

Why would Informix 11.7 return -1 as number of affected rows and Informix 11.5 return 0? It causes no error or exception, it just returns -1.

We use IBM Data Server Client 10.5. When tracing the drivers I see that with 11.5 it returns `DB2Command.ExecuteNonQuery api exit1, rc = 0 - 0` and with 11.7 it returns `DB2Command.ExecuteNonQuery api exit1, rc = 0 - -1`

Reproducable with this code:

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("IBM.Data.DB2");
IDbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Database=xxx;Server=xx.xx.xx.net:9099;UserID=xxx;Password=xxx";
connection.Open();

using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE demotable SET value = 1 WHERE dateutc = ?";
    var dateTimeParameter = command.CreateParameter();
    dateTimeParameter.Value = DateTime.UtcNow;
    command.Parameters.Add(dateTimeParameter);

    var affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Returns -1, but expected 0
}
```

UPDATE:

- Running `ExecuteScalar` with the command `select dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd2') from systables where tabid = 1` returns the expected number of rows.
- It happens on all tables, no triggers are in place.
- It works fine when using an INT as parameter, using string fails too.
- When the update is affecting a row, 1 is returned as expected.
- Same tables on different database (Informix 11.5) returns the expected number of rows.
- The database having the issue is replicated to other servers (RW instance).

Comment: If you use the `select` statement it's a normal behavior because for `select` statements, the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` is `-1` but since your problem is with `Update` you should have no problem if you are sure that `dateTimeParameter` contains value and nothing else prevent the values to being updated. Have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32736842/2946329

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about why the return value is different, I've never worked with Informix from .NET, however, the "correct" way in Informix to get the number of affected rows is selecting `DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2')` right after the update statement, not checking the return value.

Check it [in the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1488.htm)

Comment: Valid point. My question would then be has this behavior changed between 11.5 and 11.7?

Comment: Yeah, I can't answer that, I have no clue. The [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) for `UPDATE` doesn't mention any return value at all. Also, Informix doesn't seem to support `OUTPUT` or `RETURNING`, like T-SQL or Oracle do... but I'm far from being really knowledgeable in Informix, so I honestly don't know.

Comment: There may be something wrong with the [driver documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2CommandClassExecuteNonQueryMethod.html) then. It states: "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1."

Comment: @Luuk looks like so. If the documentation is for the driver version you are using, then it looks like a bug in the driver, since it does state it pretty clearly. Just to rule out other errors, does it return 0 if you don't use parameters or use other types than `DateTime`?

Comment: Hmm, just verified, it also happens with `String`, but not with `int` parameters. Maybe a culture thing?

Comment: If it happens with `String`, I doubt about culture, but maybe encoding (ex: you are sending UTF8 and the driver is expecting ASCII -probably not but just making an example-). Have you checked if it does indeed update if there's a match? Otherwise the `-1` might be indicating an error in the compiled query (which somehow is not throwing back from the db server), and not the "affected row count".

Comment: When there is a match it returns `1`. No match returns `-1`.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, sorry. If the query does work, it returning -1 doesn't make sense if the documentation states otherwise. As a simple solution for the mixup, you could just check `<=0` for no matches if you need that data, but yes, it sounds like a driver bug and probably should be reported to IBM.

Comment: Answer to your original answer: `DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2')` also returns `-1` :)

Comment: Then it's not a driver bug, it's an engine bug! :-) Since `UPDATE` doesn't seem to return anything, the driver is probably just returning the value of `DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2')`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, (I used `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteScalar` when doing the `DBINFO`. That method returns the correct number of updated rows, so again I guess the drivers don't return the correct number of updated rows. I will file an issue at IBM if I can find where :)

Comment: @Luuk do you have by any chance any triggers on that table or anything that might cause a sproc to run on? Is it only for a particular table/database or it happens always?

Comment: You mentioned that you ran `DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2')`.  Did you run this independently of your app in `dbaccess`?  If not, run an `UPDATE ...` manually, followed the the SELECT DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2').  If you get a `-1` for that result, I think it is safe to say there is a defect in that version of IDS.

Comment: Updated the question with the results that we have so far. @Jcl, thanks for helping me debug the issue. Could it be some database configuration? (I'm no DBA, and our DBA doesn't know).

Comment: I honestly have no clue. I don't know how the driver is finding out the affected rows. The only way I know is using DBINFO, but if DBINFO is returning correct results, other than a driver bug I'm totally out of ideas