# Getting null return value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I am trying to get a string return value from a stored procedure, but I am getting null. Stored procedure runs fine and return the expected string (I checked result using SQL Server Profiler) but I get empty string in my code.

```
public static string GetStringValue(string pCode)
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string returnValue = "";

    cmd.CommandText = "usp_GetStringValue";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", pCode);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result", "");
    SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@Result", "");
    cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
    sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    returnValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value);

    cmd.Connection.Close();

    return returnValue;
}
```

Here is my Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetStringValue]

@pcode Varchar (4),
@Result varchar(5000) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

 SET @Result=(Select pPath from mytable where pcode = @pcode)
 print @Result

END
```

Comment: From MSDN: *For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1* Have a look at this may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/a/32736842/2946329

Comment: what is type of variable your returning if it is output than use ParameterDirection.Output

Comment: What is the value of `cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value` ?

Comment: @Umm E Habiba Siddiqui, your code should work if the stored procedure is not doing something wrong with `RETURN`. Can you show it?

Comment: You need to show the declaration of your stored procedure, also any uses of `RETURN` withn the stored procedure. If you do not use `RETURN` and instead are using a `@Result varchar(50) OUTPUT` in your stored procedure declaration you code is the incorrect way to do it.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the @Result before adding any other parameters because it's an Output parameter. Rearrange the code as listed below. It's worked for me in the past. I will probably get flamed for this, but it's Friday.

```
     SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@Result", "");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
        sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", pCode);
```

Comment: A Output parameter is different than a Return parameter. Output parameters use `ParameterDirection.Output`, return parameters use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`, the problem is the OP has not clarified if he is trying to use a return parameter or a output parameter.

Comment: I am using Output Parameter

Comment: I have another issue that `pCode` coming from a ComboBox, first time it gives me correct output string but when I change the ComboBox value it and hit the button to get new output but it shows the first output.

Comment: it worked only one time, I execute the application again and same situation