# Search for string in SQL table unsuccessful

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, webmatrix

I'm trying to search a sql table for a specific string, and return the number of observations found. It keeps returning `-1` though, whether the string is in the table or not. Here's my code:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
    Page.title = "TestArea";


    var db = Database.Open("Cafeen");
    string SearchWord = "Jolly";

    var msg = db.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE ProductName = @SearchWord");

}

<p>@msg</p>
```

Should I perhaps use something other than `COUNT(*)`? What is the significance of `-1`? I would have assumed the expression to return `0` if the string can't be found.

Comment: You're not actually passing the SearchWord string to the db.Execute() call there, are you?

Comment: Try var msg = db.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE ProductName = '"+ SearchWord+"'");

Comment: @Jamaxack Careful there. If that string is user input, you're asking for Bobby Tables scenarios.

Comment: And not to forget to put your parameter between single quotes : `db.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE ProductName = '"+ SearchWord + "'");`

Comment: @Nyerguds Yes you are correct, but in this example problem is obvious I think

Comment: @kall2sollies this kind of query may allow user to inject malicious scripts

Comment: According to msdn Execute (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.execute(v=vs.111).aspx) is used for non-query ops. Could you try Query method for your select statement?

Comment: db.Execute returns affected rows, try QueryValue

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. It's still only returning -1 though. Could it be a problem with the table?
Edit: I'll try the QueryValue now.

Comment: Replacing Execute with QueryValue did the trick, thanks a lot! Was completely blind to that possibility.

Comment: @codroipo: you are right about injection. I think it's a beginner's approach, SQL injection is not the only design issue in the example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the WebMatrix.Data namespace. In this context you should call the [QuerySingle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.querysingle(v=vs.111).aspx) method not the Execute one because, as many have already stated, that method is for not returning rows data.

> The Execute method is used to perform non-query commands on a
>   database, such as the SQL Drop, Create, Delete, Update, and Insert
>   commands.

Moreover I suggest to change your query statement to a more performant one

```
var db = Database.Open("Cafeen");
string SearchWord = "Jolly";
string cmdText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Products 
                             WHERE ProductName = @searchWord)
                      SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";
int exists = Convert.ToInt32(db.QuerySingle(cmdText, SearchWord));
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

In `db.Execute` and `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements like **SELECT**, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Have a look at the following links may be helpful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

[How to Identify whether SQL job is successfully executed or not in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337492/how-to-identify-whether-sql-job-is-successfully-executed-or-not-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to the SQL Database, there is:

```
SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method ()
```

(re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Otherwise, refer to `Database.QueryValue` Method (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue(v=vs.111).aspx)

Both methods return a scalar value from the first column/ first row.

Also, instead of `COUNT(*)` in SQL statement you can use `COUNT(1)` for better performance.

Hope this may help.

Comment: OP is using `Database` class from `WebMatrix`.